# Meta questions not delivered to Inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, moderator-tools, global-inbox

There were a whole bunch of meta questions asked in Super User over the past few days.

[image: meta questions]

However none of these were delivered to my inbox.

[image: my inbox]

What's up with that?

Comment: That means the Stack Exchange network thinks you've been working too hard in your moderator duties and deserve a break! ;-)

Comment: Is this moderator-specific?

Comment: @Chris, yes it is.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Thanks, retagged! (Presumably [meta-tag:moderator-tools] is more appropriate than [meta-tag:10k-tools] here?)

Comment: @Chris, correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've found the issue here, has to do with how we generate, queue and send inbox items overall.  It comes down to we were using one inbox item object and in a tight loop sending that to all moderators who a) aren't employees, b) aren't devs and c) didn't post the question.

The issue is that we send almost everything to redis via it's own background fire and forget task to maximize throughput between a particular web server and redis.  Unfortunately that means that there are some extra considerations when re-using objects.  In this case, we set the AccountId to determine which inbox that item goes to *in that loop*, and since that's not synchronous, there was a chance of some mods getting dupe messages and some getting none.

This *possibility* has been corrected, but I can't confirm (easily) that it is the exact cause due to how we'd have to reproduce this race.  **Please comment if you still see this issue after the next build tonight**, as we obviously need to dig deeper for other reasons this is happening.

Comment: I just had this on Skeptics, I got the indicator that I had a new inbox item, but the new meta post isn't in my inbox.

Comment: Nick, I think it's working now, just got a notification of a meta post in my inbox.

Comment: I'm still not getting them all the time. [This post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3640/why-was-my-question-closed-351486) wasn't delivered to my inbox. Nor was the other recent meta post.

Comment: So this morning there was a new meta post, and my inbox notification count went up, but a previous notification I had already dismissed was marked as unread and the meta post wasn't there. Still broken.

Comment: yeah @Nick as nhinkle mentions, I was not notified of [Will awarding bounties remove privileges](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3648/will-awarding-bounties-remove-privileges)

Comment: @Nick can you please give us an update on the status of this? You asked us to let you know if the problem keeps happening (which as of an hour ago, it is)...

Comment: @nhinkle - We're still investigating...we have another possible fix going out in the next build, we'll compare inboxes in the morning to see if it looks any better.  Apologies for the delay...inboxes are fairly complex with a lot of overlapping pieces in motion at all times.

Comment: Well FWIW, I'm still not getting inbox notifications for meta posts, at all. `:/`

Comment: I'm getting this problem again for Skeptics, but not for Biology (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119721/notifications-for-new-meta-posts-dont-appear-in-my-inbox)