# Notifications for new meta posts don't appear in my inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meta questions not delivered to Inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110491/meta-questions-not-delivered-to-inbox)

Moderators get inbox notices for new meta posts on their sites. On Biology.SE this is working fine for me, on Skeptics.SE I now missed two new meta posts, they don't appear in my inbox. For the latest one I got the notification that I had one new item in my inbox, but everything listed in there was old.

This happened a while ago and was fixed, but something seems to cause this error again.

Comment: Something not working on Skeptics.SE? It's a conspiracy!

Comment: @yoda Do we close new bug reports as duplicates of bugs that have been marked [tag:status-completed]? I'm not sure what the best way is here.

Comment: @Fabian Well, it is the same issue and Nick's answer says to let him know via a comment if it happens again. Either way, I don't care :) All that matters is that a dev knows about it

Answer (score 2):

This is the bug that just will not die.

My working theory on this is that, for whatever reason, the meta site wasn't entirely sure who it's moderators were.  I've changed the query to be less magical, and added a load of logging around it.

If this happens again, either comment on this post or open a new meta bug with the posts you weren't notified about.