# Per-site Meta post didn't populate Moderator Inbox

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, global-inbox, top-bar

Per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120988/158781) I'm posting this issue.  I'm a moderator over on Sci-fi & Fantasy.SE.  My moderator inbox missed [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/please-help-me-to-understand-what-is-wrong-with-this-question):

[image: moderator inbox]

The Meta Question in question should show up after the moderator message and before the new meta question, as it was posted on Jan 2 (it's currently Jan 6, so '2 days ago' is Jan 4).

Comment: My moderator inbox on [french.se] is empty; I don't think http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/519/la-reflexion-envers-la-question-la-concordance-dans-une-relative-clause-avec ever appeared in it. I think the mod inbox has been missing a lot of meta questions since the new top bar was introduced.

Comment: I am noticing this as well in my Pets moderator inbox.