# Moderator messages are not shown in per-site user profile

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

I like to re-read the messages I get from moderators, savoring their style and content. I know they can be found in the global inbox:

[image: modmessage]

but being global, the inbox is cluttered  and has lots of pages to flip. I naturally expected mod messages to show up under *responses/all* tab of my profile on the site from which it came. But they do not:

[image: nomessage]

Looks like a bug.

For clarity: this is not about [moderator inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215136/259867). I am a more-or-less ordinary user, not a moderator.

Comment: FYI: Moderator messages are _also_ emailed as a rule. (Whether you receive it depends on you providing a working email, of course.)

Comment: @JonEricson Good to know, though I'm not in the habit of providing valid emails (which might correlate positively with receiving mod messages).