# When do moderators get notifications about meta posts?

Tags: support, notifications, moderator-tools, stack-exchange-button

As moderator on *Drupal Answers*, I get a notification about posts on the meta site. I noticed that I didn't get a notification (through the MultiCollider SuperDropDown) for a question, which I discovered it had an accepted answer.

Is it supposed to happen?
In which cases don't I get a notification for a question posted on the meta site?
Do the notifications include also old questions with new answers, or being edited?

Comment: If you're missing notifications; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110491/meta-questions-not-delivered-to-inbox http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119721/notifications-for-new-meta-posts-dont-appear-in-my-inbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only new questions pushed into per site metas either through migration off the main site or from a fresh bake will appear as a notification.

Edits, answers, votes, comments and other such touching will not trigger a notification in the inbox.